# Ubuntu: creating a sandbox directory returns error [500]

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I am developing a mobile app with the server running Ubuntu and Docker.
The live app connects to the directory `/config/www/rest`

To simplify the development and avoid tampering with the live files, i created a sandbox directory `/config/www/sandbox` with the copy of the working files.

The problem is that when i point the mobile app to /sandbox i get either a 405 or 500 error (depending on how i configure Nginx).

I've searched for similar threads but the solutions don't seem to work for my config. And since i'm quite new to Ubuntu and Nginx i dont know where to continue from there.

i edited the /nginx/default.save file to copy the /rest configuration and replaces rest with sandbox:

```
location ^~ /sandbox {
    root /config/www/sandbox;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /sandbox/index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

Any idea why i am getting an error when trying to reach /sandbox and how i can fix it?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you provide nginx logs corresponding to that error codes? What is the meanign of `app connects to the directory`? Which method do you using?